# Simple UPDATE query on a very big SQL table

Tags: performance, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have such a Update Query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);
SET @rows = 1;
SET @count = 0;
WHILE @rows > 0
BEGIN
update top(100000)  [dbo].[Table]
set T1=212
where T1=-10
    SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

My Tables contains more than 300 Milion rows. I have set my Azure SQL Database to `Premium P2`  with 250 DTUs. As you can see in Figure, it remains by almost 70% DTU usage.

[image]

My question is now: if I scale out my DTUs to 500, Could my update query run faster?

Comment: To answer your question, I doubt increasing the DTUs will help this update query. Your implied question is how to make the batched update run faster and we need more information to answer that. Is the T1 column indexed? How many rows do you expect to be updated?

Comment: T1 has no index, and more than 200 Milion rows should be updated

Comment: Assuming the table has clustered index, I suggest you instead update by ranges of the clustered index key. That way, you won't perform iterative scans each batch and improve concurrency too. Add table DDL to your question if you need help with that.

Comment: also no clusterd index

Comment: Generally, every table should have a clustered index. Do you have any indexes on the table? If so, you could use one of those for batching by key range.

Comment: With 2/3 of the records having the same value, it's unlikely that a clustered index on that column would do you any good, unless that index also included something with moderate selectivity...say a column or set of columns that divided that table into roughly 100K chunks. This kind of indexing will get you further than throwing more DTUs at it....meaning, better performance and less costly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on a heap (no clustered index), then what you are doing is scanning up to 300M rows to try to find the first 100k rows to update with your condition.  Then you do this potentially multiple times.  You also may spool the rows into tempdb as well.

If you are running on a clustered index on the column in the where clause, then you will do a range scan on the subset you want to update (which is more efficient). Please consider trying this.

Your current query is either cpu bound (if the pages fit in memory) or io bound (if they don’t).  Increasing the dtu will help in either case to improve your query performance.  However, you will be happier if you fix the algorithmic issues in your query performance as your next step.

Answer (score 1):

**1. If I scale out my DTUs to 500, Could my update query run faster?**

Yes, it can.

But for customers to consider, Azure SQL Database doesn't recommend you scale your DTUs directly to  improve performance of your database. Please reference:[Improving database performance with more resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview#improving-database-performance-with-more-resources)
.

**Summary:**

As a general guideline, if your CPU utilization is consistently at or above 80%, you have a running-related performance issue. If you have a running-related issue, it may be caused by insufficient CPU resources or it may be related to one of the following conditions:

1. Too many running queries
2. Too many compiling queries
3. One or more executing queries are using a sub-optimal query plan

Finally, if there are no actionable items that can improve performance of your database, you can change the amount of resources available in Azure SQL Database. You can assign more resources by changing the DTU service tier of a single database or increase the eDTUs of an elastic pool at any time.

As Clay said, for better performance and less costly, Azure also provides some suggestions to help you improve the performance. One of these suggestions is to optimize the query.
For more details, please see: [Monitoring and performance tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview).

Hops this helps.